# How to create a column from a sum which has moving fixed cells, and starts from different rows in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to populate a column with the sum of an expression that has fixed cells, but as the expression moves down the columns the fixed cells for the sum changes, as do the number of rows that need to be included. I thought I could achieve it with lead & lag functions, but no.

I hope its possible, I could write out each expression for each bin and then create a column out of the values then, but this will be part of a function that different sized datasets get fed through, so I kind of need it to be automated until the end of the time_bin.

The output column in the data is what I'm hoping for.

```
NCP <- c(96.05655668, 16.94332276, 19.8844913, 17.74200903, 17.6135507)
time_bin <- c(100,200,300,400,500)
output <- c(14.01221047, 6.51265852, 5.399067538, 3.743397662, 2.02022025)
df <- data.frame(NCP, time_bin, output)
```

The expression is will look something like: (but tidy and usable)

```
output = 
row1 = sum(((NCP/(exp(-0.0008*(time_bin[1])))-(NCP/(exp(-0.0008*0)))))) # Could use lag(time_bin with default 0 to fro last expression
row2 = sum((NCP***Starting at row 2***/(exp(-0.0008*time_bin[2])))-(NCP/(exp(-0.0008*time_bin[1])))),
row3 = sum((NCP***Starting at row 3***/(exp(-0.0008*time_bin[3])))-(NCP/(exp(-0.0008*time_bin[2])))),
row4 = sum((NCP***Starting at row 4***/(exp(-0.0008*time_bin[4])))-(NCP/(exp(-0.0008*time_bin[3])))),
row5 = sum((NCP***Starting at row 5***/(exp(-0.0008*time_bin[5])))-(NCP/(exp(-0.0008*time_bin[4]))))
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Is the second reference to `NCP` in each calculation the whole vector, or the same subset as the first reference to `NCP`?

Comment: Hi , sorry maybe not the clearest explanation, by starting at row 2 i mean sum NCP excluding the values from NCP row1, the second reference to NCP will also exclude row1, then row3 will exclude row1 and row 2 values  etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
len <- nrow(df)
df$out2 <- mapply(
  function(i, tb, tblag) sum(df$NCP[i:len]/tb - df$NCP[i:len]/tblag),
  seq_len(len), exp(-0.0008 * df$time_bin), exp(-0.0008 * c(0, df$time_bin[-len])))
df
#        NCP time_bin    output      out2
# 1 96.05656      100 14.012210 14.012210
# 2 16.94332      200  6.512659  6.512659
# 3 19.88449      300  5.399068  5.399068
# 4 17.74201      400  3.743398  3.743398
# 5 17.61355      500  2.020220  2.020220
```

If you'd like it in one calc (vectorized) instead of using `mapply`:

```r
len <- nrow(df)
e <- exp(-0.0008 * c(0, df$time_bin))
o <- outer(df$NCP, e[-1], `/`) - outer(df$NCP, e[-(len+1)], `/`)
df$out3 <- colSums(replace(o, upper.tri(o), 0))
df
#        NCP time_bin    output      out2      out3
# 1 96.05656      100 14.012210 14.012210 14.012210
# 2 16.94332      200  6.512659  6.512659  6.512659
# 3 19.88449      300  5.399068  5.399068  5.399068
# 4 17.74201      400  3.743398  3.743398  3.743398
# 5 17.61355      500  2.020220  2.020220  2.020220
```

(With this sample data, this is slightly faster than the other, but not so much that I'd be concerned with the benchmark.)

Walk-through:

- we don't need to recalculate `exp(-0.0008 * time_bin)` for each one and its lag, so doing it once and dealing with the lag later is efficient, ergo

  ```r
  e <- exp(-0.0008 * c(0, df$time_bin))
  ### verifying equality
  exp(-0.0008 * df$time_bin)
  # [1] 0.9231163 0.8521438 0.7866279 0.7261490 0.6703200
  e[-1]
  # [1] 0.9231163 0.8521438 0.7866279 0.7261490 0.6703200
  exp(-0.0008 * c(0, df$time_bin[-len]))
  # [1] 1.0000000 0.9231163 0.8521438 0.7866279 0.7261490
  e[-(len+1)]
  # [1] 1.0000000 0.9231163 0.8521438 0.7866279 0.7261490
  ```
- it's actually a little faster (I think) to calculate for all of `NCP` and discard, since the division and subtraction ops are pretty quick as well. The `outer` function takes two vectors and expands them into a matrix (as many rows as `length(vec1)`, as many columns as `length(vec2)`, applying a function to each pair. In this case, we'll divide them, so

  ```r
  outer(df$NCP, e[-1], `/`)
  #           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
  # [1,] 104.05683 112.72341 122.11182 132.28215 143.29954
  # [2,]  18.35448  19.88317  21.53918  23.33312  25.27647
  # [3,]  21.54061  23.33467  25.27814  27.38349  29.66418
  # [4,]  19.21969  20.82044  22.55451  24.43301  26.46797
  # [5,]  19.08053  20.66969  22.39121  24.25611  26.27633
  o <- outer(df$NCP, e[-1], `/`) - outer(df$NCP, e[-(len+1)], `/`)
  o
  #          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
  # [1,] 8.000269 8.666588 9.388403 10.170335 11.017392
  # [2,] 1.411160 1.528691 1.656011  1.793936  1.943347
  # [3,] 1.656121 1.794054 1.943476  2.105342  2.280690
  # [4,] 1.477680 1.600752 1.734073  1.878499  2.034954
  # [5,] 1.466981 1.589162 1.721518  1.864898  2.020220
  ```
- in general, we want column sums, but since you want the second value to start with the second `NCP`, we discard the first value in column two, first two values in column three, etc. Luckily, we can use `upper.tri()` to help shortcut this:

  ```r
  upper.tri(o)
  #       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
  # [1,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  # [2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  # [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
  # [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  # [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  replace(o, upper.tri(o), 0)
  #          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]    [,5]
  # [1,] 8.000269 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.00000
  # [2,] 1.411160 1.528691 0.000000 0.000000 0.00000
  # [3,] 1.656121 1.794054 1.943476 0.000000 0.00000
  # [4,] 1.477680 1.600752 1.734073 1.878499 0.00000
  # [5,] 1.466981 1.589162 1.721518 1.864898 2.02022
  colSums(replace(o, upper.tri(o), 0))
  # [1] 14.012210  6.512659  5.399068  3.743398  2.020220
  ```

---

dplyr-friendly approach for grouping:

```r
func <- function(ncp, i, tb, tblag) sum(ncp[i:length(ncp)]/tb - ncp[i:length(ncp)]/tblag)

df2 <- bind_rows(df, df, .id = "grp")
df2
#    grp   NCP time_bin output
# 1    1 96.06      100 14.012
# 2    1 16.94      200  6.513
# 3    1 19.88      300  5.399
# 4    1 17.74      400  3.743
# 5    1 17.61      500  2.020
# 6    2 96.06      100 14.012
# 7    2 16.94      200  6.513
# 8    2 19.88      300  5.399
# 9    2 17.74      400  3.743
# 10   2 17.61      500  2.020

df2 %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(out2 = mapply(func, list(NCP), row_number(), exp(-0.0008 * time_bin), exp(-0.0008 * lag(time_bin, default = 0)))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 x 5
#    grp     NCP time_bin output  out2
#    <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 1      96.1      100  14.0  14.0 
#  2 1      16.9      200   6.51  6.51
#  3 1      19.9      300   5.40  5.40
#  4 1      17.7      400   3.74  3.74
#  5 1      17.6      500   2.02  2.02
#  6 2      96.1      100  14.0  14.0 
#  7 2      16.9      200   6.51  6.51
#  8 2      19.9      300   5.40  5.40
#  9 2      17.7      400   3.74  3.74
# 10 2      17.6      500   2.02  2.02
```

Or using `purrr`:

```r
df2 %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(out2 = pmap_dbl(list(list(NCP), row_number(), exp(-0.0008 * time_bin), exp(-0.0008 * lag(time_bin, default = 0))), func)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Apologies for the slow reply, this is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if this should be a separate question really, but is there a way I can apply this to grouped data, so it runs separately for each group? I've been trying to use pmap but not getting very far, a tidyverse approach would be great if possible.